# Convert excel file to PDF using Python (MacOS) while retaining source formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am working on a task to automate the conversion of an excel file to a PDF using Python. I was able to achieve this by:

1. Converting the raw excel data (based on a defined range) into a pandas data frame.
2. Converting the data frame to an HTML file (intermediate step).
3. Converting the HTML file to a PDF.

I am doing this in the MacOS and it is working as expected. Code for reference:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pdfkit as pdf
import pandas as pd
wb = load_workbook(filename = '4-Grain Advertising Report.xlsx', read_only = True, data_only=True)
ws = wb['Advertising 4 Grain P&L']

data_rows = []
for row in ws['K9':'S31']:
    data_cols = []
    for cell in row:
        data_cols.append(cell.value)
    data_rows.append(data_cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
df = df.replace([None], [''], regex = True)
df.to_html('test.html', header=None, index=False)
output = 'test_output.pdf'
pdf.from_file('test.html', output)
```

However, I am unable to retain the formatting options (for example - cell coloring / bold headers etc.) that were set in the original excel spreadsheet if I follow this method. This gives me a raw table with the values in PDF format.

Any recommendations on how I can retain the source formatting and automate the conversion to PDF via Python would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to retain the formatting using Pandas. It does not support styles at all. You can try use other tools like [this](https://blog.aspose.com/2021/04/02/convert-excel-files-to-pdf-in-python/).